# A full two years? What does "a full" mean?

Tags: adjectives

> "The project is slated to be complete by end of year, *a full two
>   years* ahead of schedule."

What does "a full" mean? Is there any difference between just "two years" and "a full two years"?

Comment: It is mostly emphasis of the 'noteworthyness' of the quantity.  It also makes it clear that the person isn't cutting corners with the description (something that was 20 months ago might be referred to as staring 2 years ago - even if it were more correct for them to say "almost two years ago").  I believe that is is more about emphasis ... "take notice" to this number... it deserves more than a matter of fact acceptance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that you are talking about two whole or complete years (i.e. 365 days multiplied by 2), and not just rounding off. For instance, even 1 year and 8 months might qualify as "two years" by just rounding it off. But by saying **full**, you are emphasizing that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, addressing ambiguities due to rounding. 2.0 may be a strict synonym for the integer 2, or it may specify accuracy to 1dp. However, I'd say that the emphasis Tom mentions (equivalent to putting 'two years' in bold print) is at least as important here.